# Brakes Smoking After Driving

Tags: brakes, heat, smoke

I realized I had no brake pads. I was grinding metal on metal so I changed the rotors and put new brake pads on but still when I drive it for a little ways you can see black powder on the rims from the brakes. When you stop to look there is smoke coming from the front brake area. The brake lines are fine.

My car is a 1995 Yukon 1500 GMC with a lift and 33 inch tires on it

What do I need to replace to stop the brake pads from rubbing constantly?

Comment: Welcome to the site.  What is the make/model/year of your vehicle?

Comment: It is a 1995 Yukon 1500 GMC with a lift and 33 inch tires on it

Comment: Could be a stuck caliper piston.

Answer (score 4):

Brake dust on the rims is normal, although not usually after a short trip. It sounds like you probably have a stuck caliper. Did you replace the pads and rotors yourself? If so, did you lubricate the caliper pins? If not, get some caliper lube (the pads I usually buy come with a foil pouch of it, not sure if all do) and use it liberally on the pins. Remove the pads and slide the caliper back and forth to distribute the lube. Then re-install the pads and you should be good to go.

Comment: Sweet deal thank u and yes I did them myself but I did not lubricate it so that probably like u said is the problem

Comment: Fixing the caliper slides will help a lot, but in case you bought the cheapest pads, they typically create more dust than the more expensive ones. I say this just in case the dust doesn't go away.